# How do I run a jasmine spec in the context of one of my rails controller actions?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jasmine

So, I have a jasmine spec that is simply testing that some dom elements are retrieved with jQuery..  However, I can't get this to pass because the jasmine runner is not running on the page with the dom elements.

I am struggling to find documentation about how you attach specs to controller actions/views so that they can be testing how things actually interact with the page.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know you can't,  instead what I do is create an html jasmine fixture of the page and run the your jasmine tests in the context of the fixture.  Here is more info about how to test jquery with jasmine and setup fixtures with jasmine-jquery.

https://github.com/velesin/jasmine-jquery